# How to check Error in virtual earth /Bing Maps load

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have some failure modes scenario like:

1.When there is **restriction** to access Bing Maps(due to a firewall problem).

2.Some time Bing maps is **temporarily down**.

3.And some time **code issue or time up** problem.
How do I check for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Below links might help you.Please have a look

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/live/en-US/e275f3ee-f83e-4b92-980a-6d18b20acb9a/best-practices-bing-maps-development

Thanks 
Anil

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in the Bing Maps forums here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e57dc6f4-0d69-4358-9793-f87f3b5390bb/how-to-check-error-in-virtual-earth-bing-maps-load